# Existence of a probability measure given the probabilities

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose that $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_l \in (0, 1)$.

Is there a probability measure $\mu:\Omega\to[0, 1]$ and mutually $\mu$-independent events $A_1, \dots, A_l$ such that
$\mu(A_i)=p_i$?

For what I need, an extra hypothesis can be assumed:
There exist $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_l >0$ such that
$$p_i=\frac{f_{i-1}}{f_{i-1}+f_i},$$
where $f_0=f_l$.

Comment: You need a suitable $\Omega$ as well as $\mu$.

Comment: Your extra hypothesis with $f_0=f_l$ will put a constraint on the $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_l$.  For example if $l=1$ then you will be forced to have $p_1=\frac12$, while if $l=2$ then you will be forced to have $p_1+p_2=1$

Comment: Yes, i'm searching for suitable $\Omega$ and $\mu$. No problem about the constraint. It will make it easier to either proof or to refute the problem

Comment: Quite standard. Take a product measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$ where each component in the product is a Binomial.

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks, your idea solved the problem quite easily, to be honest. (I took $\Omega=[0, 1]^{l}$ and $A_i=[0, 1]^{i-1}\times [0, p_i] \times [0, 1]^{l-i}$.